# Node.js / Express: Possibility to create 2 separate instances from same module for 2 different routes?

Tags: node.js, express, import, module

I have 2 different routes in my epress application:

```
let readIndex= require('../services/getIndex');
let writeIndex= require('../services/getIndex');

indexRouter.route("/readindex").get(readIndex.getIndex)
indexRouter.route("/writeindex").get(writeIndex.getIndex)
```

The thing is, I have unified the logic for both routes in the same module, so I have to check the req.originalUrl parameter from which route the request comes, and I have divided my code inside that file just a little bit, depending from which request the route came.

But the problem is, it seems that both instances that I have imported from the same module (readIndex and writeIndex) behave like one and the same instance. E.G if I am doing a caching inside the module, I was expecting that both instances create their own caching instance (functions) from the module, but apparently, they both share the same variables for the cache and so on.
So if I call one route, then the next, the cache is doing as if the second called route has already been executed (after I called the first route).

What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to call / create two different instances from the same module and use them separately?

Comment: Hi, would you mind adding your code for `../services/getIndex`?

Comment: Just have two separate services for read and write, and the code which needs to be common can be another function which can be called in both.

Comment: ok thanks @Vishal-Lia, I guess that's the only way.. I copied the same code into two separate files and imported them as services for the router functions, then extracted the common used code into a separate file and imported it for both functions. I first thought creating two differently named imports from same file would create two separate instances of it.. :/

Comment: @SteveHolgado, not sure if that would be of much help, I am essentially only doing a query for req.originalUrl for what the url path is and set some variables and different database clients depending on the route. But they are used like one file unfortunately, or I would have to duplicate the whole code and do else-if queries the whole time to separate the code..